# can't start Tomcat server inside Eclipse IDE

Tags: tomcat

I am getting the following error when I am trying to start my Tomcat server
   thanks in advance

```
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Comment: What error? Please post

Comment: Hi there I have added my error. thanks

Comment: Your 8080 port is already used by another Server or program. Try to change the port for Tomcat or stop another server running on 8080.

Comment: Hi there thanks for ur reply. I have tried changing the port. But whatever port number I am giving I am still getting the same error. For example I have changed the HTTP/1.1 port to 8001. Now I am getting
 
Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8001 
 
 error. And If I go to resource monitor I cant see any process that is listening to 8001 port. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The error says that the port is already in use. There are two options;

### Change tomcat port

1. Double click on Tomcat server instance and edit the port
   [image: Tomcat Properties]
2. Save the settings

### Identify program running on port

- On Windows

  1. Open `Run` prompt. Type <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
  2. Type `perfmon /res` and press `OK`
  3. On `Resource Monitor`, on `Network` tab, look for the port under `Listening Ports`
     [image: Resource Monitor]
- On Linux

  1. Execute `netstat -tulpn | grep :<port>`, e.g. `netstat -tulpn | grep :8080`
- Find the process and kill it.

### **Update**

Here, the user was facing issues with starting server even after changing the ports and the respective ports were not displayed as used. The user got it resolved by restarting the computer. User's operating system: `Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1`.

Comment: Hi there thanks for ur reply. I have tried changing the port. But whatever port number I am giving I am still getting the same error. I have tried the second way. But In the resource monitor there is no port that is related to any process. For example I have changed the HTTP/1.1 port to 8001. Now I am getting

Comment: the above error. And If I go to resource monitor I cant see any process that is listening to 8001 port. Thanks

Comment: You may sort by ports and check once again to see if 8001 is free or not. Try some port is 9K series!

Comment: hi there I have tried 9000 series. But still getting the same error.

Comment: I have another question for you. Do I have to add or change anything in the server monitoring port :-(

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ5jh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka2aG.png

Comment: I have added the screen shots

Comment: Do you have any firewall installed?

Comment: Since the error is for specific port, let us ignore the server monitoring port for now.

Comment: I am not sure whether any firewall has been installed or not. How can I check that?

Comment: Please change All the ports to 9000 series (like 9001, 9002, 9003 9004) as mentioned by James. I tried it on my local, after starting Starting my jetty server on 8080 and then trying to start Tomcat server. It gave me error. So, i changed the ports to 9000 series and it is working as smooth as cream !

Comment: @sushmitaghosh, you got it solved? Let me know if we should troubleshoot further!

Comment: @James thanks for your support. I have set the ports to 9001, 9002 and 9003 I am getting the following error SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9002"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:9002

Comment: @yashpandey Hi there thanks for ur support. I have changed the ports to 9000 series. But I am getting the same error :-( . Any suggession

Comment: @sushmita ghosh what kind of Java program are you trying ? Is it something with socket Connections ? Try a new thing, Kill all the Java process in Task Manager or Kill command in Linux, and then try to execute.

Comment: @sushmitaghosh, could you please provide the output of the following command executed in `cmd`? `netstat -na | find "<port>"` - use the port you have configured when you run the command.

Comment: @James Jithin I am not getting anything in command line. That's my link

Comment: @yashpandey hi there I have killed all the processes but still getting the same error. :-(  thats my task manager link https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9kYn.png

Comment: @James Jithin .I have restarted my machine and it starts working. :-)

Comment: @yashpandey the server has been started. I have restarted my machine and its working perfect with the port 8080

Comment: @sushmitaghosh, please provide us the operating system with Service Pack details so that it can be mentioned in the answer. You can find the details once you right-click on "Computer" or "My Computer" and choose properties.

Comment: @James Jithin Its Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is did is : Eclipse -> Window -> Show View -> Servers -> DoubleClick on Tomcat Server -> Change admin port to "1" and leave the HTTP port to "8081" . Make sure to kill any processes which are running on port 8080. You will find your project on localhost:8081/java project name , Hope this will works!